# Reading image from AVI using cvRetrieveFrame

Tags: image, opencv

I like to check the RGB sequence of the image read by cvRetrieveFrame. I checked as follow

```
    frame_data = cvRetrieveFrame(readerAvi);
    cvShowImage("imageOrg", frame_data.Ptr());
    cvWaitKey();
    cvDestroyWindow("imageOrg");
    IplImage* r = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(frame_data.Ptr()), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);    //r
    IplImage* g = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(frame_data.Ptr()), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);    //g
    IplImage* b = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(frame_data.Ptr()), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);    //b
    cvSplit(frame_data.Ptr(), r, g, b, NULL);
    IplImage* c = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(frame_data.Ptr()), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3);
    cvMerge(r,0,0,0,c);     
    cvShowImage("imageT", c);
    cvWaitKey();
    cvDestroyWindow("imageT");
```

I put r,g,b into `cvMerge(r,0,0,0,c);` alternately. But I see only yellow image. What is worng with my test code?
I did `cvSplit(frame_data.Ptr(), b, g, r, NULL);`
Then `cvMerge(b,NULL,NULL,NULL,c);`made yellow.
      `cvMerge(NULL,g,NULL,NULL,c);` made pink. And `cvMerge(NULL,NULL,r,NULL,c);` made green.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenCV store image BGR order and cvSplit should be like this

```
cvSplit(src, b, g, r, NULL);
```

and for blue channel the merge should be

```
cvMerge(b,NULL,NULL,NULL,c);
```

For green

```
cvMerge(NULL,g,NULL,NULL,c);
```

For red

```
cvMerge(NULL,NULL,r,NULL,c);
```

If you are getting colour other than RGB while merging the other two channel are not empty in your destination image, so just do `cvZero(c)` before merging.

You can also  try below code with some image

```
    IplImage *src=cvLoadImage("img.jpg",1);

    IplImage* r = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(src), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);    //r
    IplImage* g = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(src), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);    //g
    IplImage* b = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(src), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);    //b
    cvSplit(src, b, g, r, NULL);
    IplImage* c = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(src), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3);

    cvMerge(b,NULL,NULL,NULL,c);
    cvShowImage("Blue Channel", c);

    cvZero(c);
    cvMerge(NULL,g,NULL,NULL,c);
    cvShowImage("Green Channel", c);

    cvZero(c);
    cvMerge(NULL,g,NULL,NULL,c);
    cvShowImage("Green Channel", c);

    cvZero(c);
    cvMerge(NULL,NULL,r,NULL,c);
    cvShowImage("Red Channel", c);

    cvMerge(b,g,r,NULL,c);
    cvShowImage("Three Channel", c);
    cvWaitKey();
```